# Parsing CSV in Lambda using Node JS

Tags: node.js, csv, npm, aws-lambda

I am trying to parse a CSV file from S3 with Node JS hosted by AWS Lambda. I have tried using both `fast-csv` and `csv-parser` npm. However, both of my solutions would result in Lambda function failure caused by `Error: write after end`. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I am declaring the stream variables inside the handler. Updated code.

```
// dependencies
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const parse = require('csv-parser')
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  // read S3 object stream
  var s3Stream = s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.`;
        console.log(message);
        callback(message);
    } else {
        console.log('CONTENT TYPE:', data.ContentType);
        callback(null, data.ContentType);
    }
  }).createReadStream();


  // read CSV with fast-csv
  // options for fast-csv npm
  var options = {
    headers:true,
    escape:'\\',
    trim:true,
  };

  csv.fromStream(s3Stream, options).on("data", function(data) {
    data.id = uuidv4();
    data.createDate = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log(data);
  }).on("error", function(data) {
    console.error("Got an error: " + data);
  }).on("end", function() {
    console.log("Done reading.");
  });


  // read CSV with csv-parser
  var otherOptions = {
    columns : true,
    auto_parse : true,
    escape : '\\',
    trim : true,
  };
  var parser = parse(otherOptions);
  parser.on('data', function(data) {
    data.id = uuidv4();
    data.createDate = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log(data);
  })
  .on('end',function(data) {
    //do something wiht csvData
    console.log(data);
  });
  s3Stream.pipe(parser);
};
```

Comment: This looks like it may already have been answered? Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578998/stream-transformations-in-aws-lambda-result-in-write-after-end-error/33696017.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream transformations in AWS Lambda result in write after end error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578998/stream-transformations-in-aws-lambda-result-in-write-after-end-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the callback:

```
var s3Stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
```

I really hope they document all these well.